# Trouble with reading JSON file in C# code

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I'm having some issues reading a specific JSON file. My code is reading other JSON files so I'm guessing I'm doing something pretty stupid but I've stared at this for about an hour without success. I have the following code

```
        List<VFData> visualFieldData;


        public class VFData
        {
            public double x { get; set; }
            public double y { get; set; }
            public string type { get; set; }
            public double contrast { get; set; }
        }

        private void LoadVFDataJSONFile(string VFdataFile )
        {
            string jsonStream;
            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(VFdataFile))
            {
                jsonStream = r.ReadToEnd();
            }
            visualFieldData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<VFData>>(jsonStream);
        }


The JSON file has the following format


[
  {
    "x": -4.0,
    "y": 4.0,
    "type": "vf",
    "contrast": 0.670277655
  },
  {
    "x": -14.0,
    "y": 4.0,
    "type": "vf",
    "contrast": 0.407872766
  },
  {
    "x": -24.0,
    "y": 4.0,
    "type": "vf",
    "contrast": 0.372877628
  },
  {
    "x": -34.0,
    "y": 4.0,
    "type": "vf",
    "contrast": 0.4652638
  },
  {
    "x": -4.0,
    "y": 14.0,
    "type": "vf",
    "contrast": 0.399946272
  },
  {
    "x": -4.0,
    "y": 24.0,
    "type": "vf",
    "contrast": 0.420959234
  },
  {
    "x": -14.0,
    "y": 14.0,
    "type": "vf",
    "contrast": 0.3694598
  },
  {
    "x": -14.0,
    "y": 24.0,
    "type": "vf",
    "contrast": 0.4507869
  },
  {
    "x": -24.0,
    "y": 14.0,
    "type": "vf",
    "contrast": 0.4334121
  },
  {
    "x": 4.0,
    "y": 4.0,
    "type": "vf",
    "contrast": 0.515925348
  },
  {
    "x": 14.0,
    "y": 4.0,
    "type": "vf",
    "contrast": 0.487090856
  },
  {
    "x": 24.0,
    "y": 4.0,
    "type": "vf",
    "contrast": 0.5159793
  },
  {
    "x": 4.0,
    "y": 14.0,
    "type": "vf",
    "contrast": 0.3921606
  },
  {
    "x": 4.0,
    "y": 24.0,
    "type": "vf",
    "contrast": 0.4164949
  },
  {
    "x": 14.0,
    "y": 14.0,
    "type": "vf",
    "contrast": 0.392385662
  },
  {
    "x": 14.0,
    "y": 24.0,
    "type": "vf",
    "contrast": 0.426395863
  },
  {
    "x": 24.0,
    "y": 14.0,
    "type": "vf",
    "contrast": 0.4305214
  },
  {
    "x": 4.0,
    "y": -4.0,
    "type": "vf",
    "contrast": 0.377473235
  },
  {
    "x": 14.0,
    "y": -4.0,
    "type": "vf",
    "contrast": 0.355986029
  },
  {
    "x": 24.0,
    "y": -4.0,
    "type": "vf",
    "contrast": 0.3789097
  },
  {
    "x": 4.0,
    "y": -14.0,
    "type": "vf",
    "contrast": 0.396197081
  },
  {
    "x": 4.0,
    "y": -24.0,
    "type": "vf",
    "contrast": 0.363053441
  },
  {
    "x": 14.0,
    "y": -14.0,
    "type": "vf",
    "contrast": 0.384389132
  },
  {
    "x": 14.0,
    "y": -24.0,
    "type": "vf",
    "contrast": 0.440146685
  },
  {
    "x": 24.0,
    "y": -14.0,
    "type": "vf",
    "contrast": 0.387488931
  },
  {
    "x": -4.0,
    "y": -4.0,
    "type": "vf",
    "contrast": 0.366485029
  },
  {
    "x": -14.0,
    "y": -4.0,
    "type": "vf",
    "contrast": 0.392450541
  },
  {
    "x": -24.0,
    "y": -4.0,
    "type": "vf",
    "contrast": 0.428462267
  },
  {
    "x": -34.0,
    "y": -4.0,
    "type": "vf",
    "contrast": 0.394372374
  },
  {
    "x": -4.0,
    "y": -14.0,
    "type": "vf",
    "contrast": 0.377464861
  },
  {
    "x": -4.0,
    "y": -24.0,
    "type": "vf",
    "contrast": 0.372114331
  },
  {
    "x": -14.0,
    "y": -14.0,
    "type": "vf",
    "contrast": 0.377241641
  },
  {
    "x": -14.0,
    "y": -24.0,
    "type": "vf",
    "contrast": 0.42327565
  },
  {
    "x": -24.0,
    "y": -14.0,
    "type": "vf",
    "contrast": 0.407872945
  }
]
```

I get the following error

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WindowsFormsApp1.Form1+VFData]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'x', line 1, position 5.'

Comment: Sounds like the input is not the same as proposed by you. Double-check you use the correct file and it has the correct content

Answer (score 0):

Always test your assumptions

```
var jsonData = @"[
  {
    ""x"": -4.0,
    ""y"": 4.0,
    ""type"": ""vf"",
    ""contrast"": 0.670277655
  },
  {
    ""x"": -14.0,
    ""y"": 4.0,
    ""type"": ""vf"",
    ""contrast"": 0.407872766
  },
  {
    ""x"": -24.0,
    ""y"": -14.0,
    ""type"": ""vf"",
    ""contrast"": 0.407872945
  }
]";
var visualFieldData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<VFData>>(jsonData);
```

The above code runs fine with no exceptions (I tested with your full json example, just shortened it for the answer). I'd recommend running in debug mode to see what string you're actually trying to convert, or adding some kind of log statement to show the json string.

There's no way for us to know if you're reading the wrong file, if the file has corrupted characters, or if some other issue is happening - but the one thing I can say for sure is that the JSON in your question works fine with the class being deserialized to

Edit: Looking at the error I do have a guess, the following code produces the same error

```
try
{
    var jsonData = @"
      {
        ""x"": -4.0,
        ""y"": 4.0,
        ""type"": ""vf"",
        ""contrast"": 0.670277655
      }";
    var visualFieldData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<VFData>>(jsonData);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Info(ex.Message);
        logger.Info(ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

It could be that your file has a single item, and not an array of items. The solution is just to deserialize to a single instance of VFData instead of a list

```
var visualFieldData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VFData>(jsonData);
```